# How to make all quotes italicised

Tags: formatting, quoting

I want to italicise all the quotes in my paper. By that I mean that everything in the `quote` environment is italicised to help differentiate it from the main text.

I've seen a few threads talking about making new environments/commands, but how would I modify a pre-existing default one like `quote`?

Comment: Can you please give some feedback to the answers below?

Comment: Yep, just needed a chance to log back in!

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what I did wrong in the post above - it was a clear question that needed a clear answer, rather than debate.

Comment: No debate, at all. The welcome message is a standard one we use over here to welcome new users and try to be nice with them :) The only things wrong in your question is that you said 'quotes' instead of 'quote' and to highlight TeX code you have to use backticks and not braces. If you don't mind, I'll edit the question, so you'll see how to do that next time. Happy TeXing and again welcome to the site :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can load the package [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) and add the line

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\itshape}
```

to your preamble. In this way, each time a `quote` environment starts, the italic shape is selected.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\itshape}

\begin{document}
Hello

\begin{quote}
  aaa

  bbb
\end{quote}

Hello again
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The good solution is to use the [quoting-package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/quoting).

```
\usepackage[noorphans,font=itshape]{quoting}
```

Change all your

```
\begin{quote}
[citation text]
\end{quote}
```

to

```
\begin{quoting}
[citation text]
\end{quoting}
```

I suggest you read the manual to learn the other useful options.

Comment: This also seems to work - although I prefer the modification of the {quote} environment rather than changing all the environments to something new!

Comment: It's a bit awkward to say "the good solution" about a solution that does not answer the original question. The original question, as is, definitely has its merit, for instance when exporting from emacs `org-mode` to `LaTeX`, when org-mode quote blocks automatically become LatTeX `quote` environments.